# Make a local function as global

Tags: javascript, function

In Javascript with ProcessingJS.

If I define a function outside the draw function, how can I pass this function to the draw function (without copying and pasting inside the draw function)?

```
var myFunction = function()
{
    code;
}

var draw = function(){ 
    myFunction(); 
};
```

How do you make a function global?

I use a limited environment, Khan Academy, and only the simplest functions and commands are available.

Thanks for your replies, and sorry to be a beginner.

Comment: remove the var in front of myFunction

Comment: shouldnt it be function myFunction(){}?? @Oriol

Comment: @Mox Ah, sorry, I read `var myFunction = function() {code;}` and thought you suggested `myFunction = function() {code;}`.

Comment: I feel that the question title is misleading

Comment: What other title do you suggest? I can't remove the "var", I don't know why, but it's needed on Khan Academy.

Comment: Are you getting an error with the above example? Khan Academy will probably tell you that you need a semicolon after the function's closing brace, and of course you can't just use `code;` because that doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass your function as a parameter. For example:

```
var myFunction = function() {code;}

var draw = function(f) { f(); };

draw(myFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Khan Academy too. There are strict syntax rules that don't make sense anywhere else. To answer the question,

```
var myFunction = function () {
    /* Stuff */
}, draw = function () {
    myFunction();
};
```

will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks. Perfect answer in my case. Other answers are interesting too.

Comment: I would be interested to discuss with you about the differences in the syntax.

Comment: There are some famous examples, such as `function myFunction () {}` being disallowed, semicolons necessary on every able line, etc.

Comment: If you want to contact me on KA my username is @rak235711

Answer (score 0):

You're using invalid syntax. If you want to make a global function and call it inside `draw()`, just declare it like a regular function:

```
var myFunction = function () {   // <-- note the "=" sign and "function" keyword here
    code;
};

var draw = function (){ 
    myFunction(); 
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I've been careless and forgot a part, but it was right when I wrote it in the console. It's fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is to call myFunction inside the draw function.

Here is how you would do that:

```
var myFunction = function(){
    //your code here
}   

var draw = function(fun){
   fun();
}
```

Basically, if you want to call myFunction() inside the draw() function, you have to pass a function into draw(), this is called a parameter. Like so:  `var draw = (fun)` Here, fun is a function being passed into draw. Now you just need to call it using fun();

Good luck!